# Where do I upload a Joomla extension when trying to install it manually?

Tags: extensions

I'm trying to install a Joomla extension manually.  The ZIP file is too large to upload using the extension manager so my question is where do I upload the file on my server to install it manually using the Joomla extension manager?

Answer (score 2):

Normally the best place to FTP upload the extension's ZIP file is in the /public_html/tmp folder on your server. However you can customise the location however you wish and point the extension manager to install from any location on your server.