# Error installing AdsManager Extension: Maximum PHP file upload size is too small

Tags: extensions

As I try to install [AdsManager](http://www.joomprod.com/products/classified-ads.html) extension through Upload Package File option, getting the Error:

*There was an error uploading this file to the server.
Maximum PHP file upload size is too small: This is set in php.ini in both upload_max_filesize and post_max_size settings of your PHP settings (located in php.ini and/or .htaccess file).*

Do I need to edit php.ini settings as instructed above or is there a quicker, better way to download this extension?

Comment: Yes. You need change php.ini and try upload again. But maybe this was a limitation In your host plan.

Comment: This is a similar question to [Where do I upload a Joomla extension when trying to install it manually?](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/15958/120)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with one of this options:

- If you have access to your **php.ini**, change the values and restart your webserver:

**upload_max_filesize=64M
 
post_max_size=64M**

Also you can increase this value 
**max_execution_time=300**

- If you don't have access to this file, you can add this values in your **.htaccess** file

**php_value upload_max_filesize 64M

php_value post_max_size 64M

php_value max_execution_time 300**

Regards.

Comment: Adding the above 3-line code into htaccess.txt file (I did it through C Panel File Manager, GoDaddy (http://splendidjoomla.blogspot.in/2016/04/right-way-to-append-htaccess.html)?  Not successful as trying to install shows the same error message.

Comment: You should rename your file **htaccess.txt** to **.htaccess**

Comment: So, the same is possible through ftp and not c-panel?

Comment: Yes, download the **htaccess.txt** via FTP, add the code, save, rename the file to **.htaccess** and upload the file again via FTP, replace the old file with the new file.

Comment: While working with htaccess.txt and .htaccess somewhere messed and now the site is showing 500 Internal Server Error. Is there any standard htaccess.txt and .htaccess script which I can fresh upload to restore the website?

Comment: After removing 3-line code (http://www.splendidjoomla.blogspot.in/) from the bottom, the website is restored. I understand I have put the code in wrong place.

Comment: Maximum PHP file upload size is too small is faced when uploading fresh applications like Gantry framework. If under GoDaddy hosting, through C-panel, Software, Select PHP Version, Switch to PHP Options, raise upload_max_filesize from existing 2M or 4M to 8M which in most case should be suffice. Although, there is option to raise up to 1G, but beware as other functions are compromised and so against the principle of optimization.

Answer (score 2):

**Install from Folder Installation Method**

If unable to update the PHP limitations via php.ini or .htaccess, an alternative install method is to expand the extension installation file into a folder on your local machine e.g. `/adsmanager` and then upload this folder via FTP to the `/tmp` or similar folder in your Joomla install.

Go to `Extensions -> Manage -> Install` in the back-end, click on the "Install from Folder" tab, enter the location of your install folder and click on "Install" as in the following example:

[image: Install from Folder]